# Microsoft SSRS - Custom web interface

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reporting

Our team has designed a nice front end interface using HTML 5 and PHP. However, we don't have much experience with SSRS integration. Currently we are bringing in the report using an iFrame and it shows the SSRS toolbar as well.

I, myself spent an hour trying to search how to accomplish this task but the search results haven't really turned up anything useful.

Hoping to get some help on here.

Server runs Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.0 and SQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use a frame. For more control you could consume the rs web service and then, inside  your app add instructions to have it returned as html. This would add the complexity of calling ssrs with a request for a report.